# Creating a pop-up image from PHP code

Tags: php

I am wanting to create a popup window to display an image which has been retrieved from my database

So far, my query shows the data in my database, but how do I create a pop-up link to show the image when the link is clicked by the user?

```
$dbQuery="SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id = '$userID' ";

$dbResult=mysqli_query($db_connection, $dbQuery) or die (mysqli_error($db_connection));
echo "<table cellspacing=\"5\" class=\"recordsTableBG\"> <thead      
    class=\"recordsTableHeader\">";
echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Amount</th><th>Description</th><th>Filename</th> 
    <th>Project ID</th><th>Status</th></tr></thead>';
echo '<tr class="alternateRowColor">';
    '<tr>';
while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)){

    echo "<img src = 'uploaded/$image' width = '200' height = '200'>";
    // display row with expense
    echo '<td>'. $dbRow['id'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $dbRow['user_id']. '</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $dbRow['image']. '</td>';
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: You'll need to use some JavaScript if you want to do a popup. You can't do this alone with PHP. Are you just trying to generate a link, or are you trying to do the actual popup part?

Comment: What KevBot says is correct. Most sites have moved away from acutal pop-ups today, though, as they are automatically blocked by browsers. Using a modal or similar would be advisable.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to use some sort of JavaScript? Can you please supply some guidance on how to use JavaScript for this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be extra work to do it with PHP. If you are uniquely identifying every image with an "ID", then you would need to echo a link along with id and user_id. It would be something like this:

```
while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)){

    echo "<img src = 'uploaded/$image' width = '200' height = '200'>";
    // display row with expense
    echo '<td>'. $dbRow['id'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $dbRow['user_id']. '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?imageid='.$dbRow['id'].'>
    Click here to view image</a></td>';

}
```

This opens a new page. If you want a popup, you would want to use `javascript:window.open()` method on the link. Note that there are other and better ways than `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`. The idea is you need to append the `ID` to the link you want as a GET parameter.

On the new page, you need to include enough functionality to retrieve the record from the database using the `ID` and show the image the same way you've written.

This is not really the best way to do this. The best way according to me is "use javascript and display a div (originally hidden) that overlaps on everything else on the page (highest `Z-index`) that can be styled as a window with a close button. The trick is to `show` the div when the link is clicked, and then `hide` it back when the close button is clicked.